# Stop function from re- executing for one second with settimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to prevent my function from re-executing for one second after it's last executed. I've tried the method below, but it doesn't work.

```js
function displayOut() {
 
 // images
 document.getElementById("imgBox").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + db.rooms[roomLoc].roomImg + ")";
 // Diologue box
 diologueBox.innerHTML = ""; // Clear Box
 teleTyperDiologue(db.rooms[roomLoc].description + 
  " The room contains: " +
   (function() {
    let x = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < db.items.length; i++) {
     if (db.items[i].location === roomLoc && db.items[i].hidden === false) {
      x += db.items[i].name + ", "
     }
    }
    x = x.slice(0, x.length -2);
    if (x === "") {
     x = " nothing of special interest";
    }
    return x;
   })()
  + ".");
 pause();
};

function pause() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  // Wait one second!
 }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: JavaScript cant be made to 'wait', it is non-blocking in nature. You will need to pass a function to setTimeout, and that will get executed after the specified time. I would suggest you read up more about how callbacks are used in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pattern like this:

```js
var executing = false;

function myFunc() {
  if(!executing) {
    executing = true;
    
    //Code
    console.log('Executed!');
    //End code
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      executing = false;
    }, 1000);
  }
}

setInterval(myFunc, 100);
```

So in your case, this would look like this:

```
var executing = false;

function displayOut() {
  if(!executing) {
    executing = true;

    // images
    document.getElementById("imgBox").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + db.rooms[roomLoc].roomImg + ")";
    // Diologue box
    diologueBox.innerHTML = ""; // Clear Box
    teleTyperDiologue(db.rooms[roomLoc].description + 
    " The room contains: " +
    (function() {
      let x = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < db.items.length; i++) {
        if (db.items[i].location === roomLoc && db.items[i].hidden === false) {
          x += db.items[i].name + ", "
        }
      }
      x = x.slice(0, x.length -2);
      if (x === "") {
        x = " nothing of special interest";
      }
      return x;
    })()
    + ".");

    setTimeout(function() {
      executing = false;
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

Comment: That worked, but for some reason it stops the background images from updating when the function runs again.

Comment: @Cuckoo That sounds like a different problem?

Comment: @Cuckoo Sorry, it seems one line was unintentionally modified. Try again with update.

Comment: Same problem I'm afraid. :(

Comment: @Cuckoo Any errors in console? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: [Here's the link](http://infinitedv.co.uk/textad/index_03.html) This is the working script with your code added. The problem I'm having is that navigating between rooms too quickly, causes the teletype to try and write dialogue on top of other dialogue that is still being written. Your script fixes that, but the background image is getting stuck for some reason. Try it without rushing to see how it performs normally.

Answer (score 0):

This one will achieve that:

```
function run () {
  console.log('Im running');
  pause(1000);
};

function pause(s) {
  console.log('Im paused');
  setTimeout(() =>{
    run();
  }, s)
};

run();
```

The code above will run every 1 sec but if you want to make sure the function cant be runned again until you decide then you could use a flag instead like:

```
let canExecute = true;
function run () {
  if (canExecute) {
    console.log('Im running');
    canExecute = false;
    pause(1000);
  }
};

function pause(s) {
  console.log('Im paused');
    setTimeout(() =>{
      canExecute = true;
    }, s)
};

run();
run();
run();
setTimeout(() =>{
  run();
}, 2000)
```

This code will execute run function twice, first on time and then one more after 2 sec.

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't stop the function from executing.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this but it doesn't stop me from executing the function again. I'll try and play with it but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use throttle (http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) or debounce (http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) from underscore, one of those should fit your needs